# Is it possible with Grunt to merge all js/css files in a specific folder in to one js/css file?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm new with Grunt and I wasn't able to find what I'm looking for.

I have this folder's structure configuration :

```
app/
public/
    assets/
        ... some javascript/css libs like jQuery, Bootstrap, etc
    css/
    js/
    img/
```

What I'd like to do is compress all the js files in `public/assets/` into one `assets.js` file that would be in `js/assets.js`, and do the same for all the css files into `assets.css` in `css/assets.css`.

Moreover, I'd like those two assets.js/css file to be compressed.

A link to a solution or some start of a solution is all I need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to concatenate your files and then run them through a minifier. Grunt has plenty of plugins that will do these things but some of the more popular ones are [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat), [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin).

These tasks have plenty of options available to taylor them to your needs but this should help you get started.

As sample configuration for the `concat` task would be something like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    js: {
      src: ['public/assets/a.js', 'public/assets/b.js', 'public/assets/c.js'],
      dest: 'public/js/assets.js',
    },
    js: {
      src: ['public/assets/a.css', 'public/assets/b.css', 'public/assets/c.css'],
      dest: 'public/css/assets.css',
    },
  },
});
```

Then for your minify js task:

```
uglify: {
    js: {
      files: {
        'public/assets/js/assets.min.js': 'public/assets/js/assets.js'
      }
    }
  }
```

And finally, css minify task:

```
cssmin: {
  files: {
    'public/assets/css/assets.min.css' : 'public/assets/css/assets.css'
  }
}
```